# How to use mat-paginator on other than MatTableDataSource?

Tags: angular, pagination, treeview, mat-pagination

I want paginator on below dataSource but it showing error 
**property 'paginator' does not exist on type 'MatTreeFlatDataSource<TreeNode, TreeFlatNode>'**

```
this.treeFlattener = new MatTreeFlattener(this.transformer, this.getLevel, this.isExpndable, this.getChildren);
this.treeControl = new FlatTreeControl<TreeFlatNode>(this.getLevel, this.isExpndable);

dataSource: MatTreeFlatDataSource<TreeNode, TreeFlatNode>;
this.dataSource = new MatTreeFlatDataSource(this.treeControl, this.treeFlattener);
```

TRIED

```
this.dataSource.paginator=this.paginator;
this.dataSource.data.paginator=this.paginator;
```